# shell script that allows to empty a file when it exceeds a certain size

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm looking for a Linux script that allows to empty the contents of a file  when it exceeds a certain size for example 50 kB.

I tried this script :

```
#!/bin/bash
find /home/walid/Documents -type f -size +50k -exec echo >"{}" \;
```

but it does not work.

On the other hand it works well for deleting files:

```
#!/bin/bash
find /home/walid/Documents -type f -size +50k -exec rm "{}" \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your redirection (`>`) takes place before starting `find`.  You probably now have a file of name `{}`.

I propose to use `truncate` instead of a redirection for overwriting the file:

```
find /home/walid/Documents -type f -size +50k -exec truncate --size 0 "{}" \;
```

Comment: @A.Walid Welcome to Stackoverflow!  If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by pressing the check mark left to it.  If an answer contributes or is otherwise valuable, please upvote it by pressing the upwards triangle left to it.  "Thank you" comments on the other hand are polite but deemed unnecessary (to reduce text) if any of the other are options are used.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to this:

```
find /home/walid/Documents -type f -size +50k -exec cp /dev/null {} \;
```

That should work in any [*nix like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-like) operating system, but also you could give a try to `truncate -s 0 filename`

```
find /home/walid/Documents -type f -size +50k -exec truncate -s 0 {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

A little tweak on your first script should work fine:

```
#!/bin/bash
find /home/walid/Documents -type f -size +50k -exec sh -c 'echo -n > {}' \;
```